Excel: Sum all quantities of unique items across all sheets
I have data spread across several sheets that includes (amongst other things) a part number and a quantity associated with that part. The part number and quantity appears many times in each sheet. I want to SUM all of the quantities for each part number across all sheets.
Example of the data in one of the sheets:
Qty.   Part Number   Description   Price
 3       ABC123       Widget 1      $123
 2       AAA111       Widget 2      $111
 5       ZZZ321       Widget 3      $222
 8       ABC123       Widget 1      $123
 1       ZZZ321       Widget 3      $222

This format is the same across several sheets. Let's say for example I had 3 sheets of the same data shown above - I want to put the Qty. value for each Part Number into a 4th sheet such that ABC123 = 33, AAA111 = 6, and ZZZ321 = 12.
I was able to do this with a PivotTable, however this is not useful for me because I need to manipulate this data in ways that breaks the PivotTable. Any ideas?

With Office 365 we can use TOCOL with a 3D reference. Then use either GROUPBY(Currently only available for Insiders(beta)) or UNIQUE,FILTER,and SUM.
=LET(
    x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet3!A2:B100,1),2),
    GROUPBY(TAKE(x,,-1),TAKE(x,,1),SUM,0,0))

The 3D reference is noted by the Sheet1:Sheet3! this will include all sheets located between those two book ends.  So make sure they refer to the first and last sheet in order of the tabs and that no other sheets are in between.  It also assumes that the data is in the same columns on each sheet.
The TOCOL will create a list 1 column wide of the data, skipping any blanks.  Then with WRAPROWS we put it back to a 2 column array.  We pass that array into GROUPBY to do the grouping and sum.


For those with Excel 365 but not GROUPBY:
=LET(
    x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet3!A2:B100,1),2),
    unq,UNIQUE(TAKE(x,,-1)),
    HSTACK(unq,BYROW(unq,LAMBDA(z,SUM(FILTER(TAKE(x,,1),TAKE(x,,-1)=z))))))

Here the array is passed to UNIQUE to create an unique array.  Then we iterate that array using BYROW and FILTER the original array on each unique item and sum the results.


Thanks, this is helpful and I can see where you are going with it. I should clarify that my destination sheet for this data already has the Part Number available on it, and I need to associate the totalled quantity with that part number, rather than making a new column for that.

Then just change the UNIQUE(TAKE(x,,-1)) to your range of part number.

Love the use of GROUPBY()+WRAPROWS()+TOCOL(). Sir one more VSTACK() could also work! =LET(x, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet3!A2:D100), y, TAKE(x,,1), GROUPBY(y,TAKE(x,,-1),SUM,,0,,y<>0))

This should be a comment but I'm not allowed to do that yet. There are a multitude of ways to solve this one.
A simple method is to use a grouping of SUMIFS to tally the total count of parts from different sheets based on criteria.
Say you have lists in sheet 1 and sheet 2 and want to total on sheet 3 you would use something like this:
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B,Sheet3!B2)+SUMIFS(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet3!B2)
I'm not usually a fan of such methods due to the expansive range of this method and would lean towards turning the raw data into tables then creating the formula. Say the table on sheet one is named Table1 and the table on sheet 2 is named Table2 your formula would look something like this:
=SUMIFS(Table1[Qty.],Table1[Part Number],Sheet3!B2)+SUMIFS(Table2[Qty.],Table2[Part Number],Sheet3!B2)
Ultimately the best solution depends on your use case and how the data is being fed into the spreadsheet. If your raw data is static then a simple formula will work fine. If your data is live or often modified with new sheets added then you may want to lean towards a different solution which will reduce the amount of rework in future iterations.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
